# How to sort PHP multidimensional associative array with a selected key value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

How to sort following php array with its 'zindex' key value

```
$array = array('the-1'=> array('name'=>'lorem','pos'=>array('top'=>'90','left'=>'80'),'zindex'=>2),
        'the-2'=> array('name'=>'ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'190','left'=>'180'),'zindex'=>1),
        'the-3'=> array('name'=>'lorem ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'20','left'=>'30'),'zindex'=>3)
        )
```

Is there any php function for getting the output as follows,

```
$array = array(
        'the-2'=> array('name'=>'ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'190','left'=>'180'),'zindex'=>1),
        'the-1'=> array('name'=>'lorem','pos'=>array('top'=>'90','left'=>'80'),'zindex'=>2),
        'the-3'=> array('name'=>'lorem ipsum','pos'=>array('top'=>'20','left'=>'30'),'zindex'=>3)
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

This should do the trick for you... It did for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($array,function($el1,$el2){
    return $el1-$el2;
});
```

Requires PHP5.3

if you need older versions' support replace anonymous function by usual one